# SQL Server database upgrade - 2016 to 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssms

We upgraded our SQL server from 2016 to 2019. Now we need to upgrade/convert our custom 2016 database to make it 2019 compatible. What's the process? We are running `SQL Server management studio 2019` and imported our 2016 db successfully.
There is a  `Database > Properties >Options` where compatibility level can be set to `Sql Server 2019`.

We can successfully run queries against the 2016 db under 2019 compatibility mode in SSMS. Is that enough or does it require more effort for the db conversion at the client environment?

I am a newbie with DB stuff and hence all inputs are very much appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) article has all the information you need necessary to complete the upgrade. [If you have set the compatibility level you should be fine.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Basically, no worries if it's working fine.

Comment: @Ramhound - Thank you :)